# Show "loading" while a new image is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have

```
<img src="..." class="myImage">
<a href="..." class="changeImage">

$(function(){
   $('a.changeImage').click(function(){
       $('img.myImage').attr('src',NEWVALUE);
   });
});
```

When I click the link, i inject a new src to `.myImage`. Is it possibile to show a loading image while the new src is loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [load event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) (untested code)

```
<img src="smallLoader.png" alt="loading" id="loading" />
<img alt="bigImage" id="bigImage" style="display:none" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#bigImage').load(function() {
        $('#loading').hide();
        $('#bigImage').show();
    });

    $('#bigImage').attr("src", "bigimage.png");
});
</script>
```

Comment: jusdt don't forget to include everything inside $(document).ready

Comment: I edited the code. While the way the code as listed doesn't require it per-se, $(document).ready is an appropriate measure in this case especially if you move the script somewhere else.

Comment: You need to add the `load` handler before changing the `src` property for this to work reliably.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you should use image preloading

```
var newImage = new Image();
var loadingSrc = 'loading.gif';
$('img.myImage').attr('src', loadingSrc);
newImage.onload = function() {
    $('img.myImage').attr('src', newImage.src);
};
newImage.src = NEWVALUE;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function(){
   $('a.changeImage').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       //show the loading div
       $('img.myImage').attr('src',NEWVALUE);
       $("img").trigger("onload");
   });

$("img").bind("onload",function(){

 //remove the loading div
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PrXSW/9/

Comment: totally agree but in the fiddle without explicit trigger it was not triggering

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to the jquery.blockui plugin. It may fit your needing.

Answer (score 1):

the simplest solution would be to declare the loading img via CSS as `background-image`.

```
#loaded-image {
    /* shows loading icon until picture is fully loaded */
    background-image: url(loading.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```